# Excel Spreadsheet to generate texts in a word template

Tags: python-3.x, excel, ms-word

I was wondering if you know whether it is possible to generate text in a word template using an excel spreadsheet.

For example, suppose I have a survey which asks such kind of questions

```
1) How many times do you go out?
1- Not at all
2- once
3- Twice

2) How many reliable friends do you have?
1- Not at all
2- one
3- Two
```

This will generate a spreadsheet

```
Person 1: 1,3
Person 2: 3,1
Person 3: 2,2
Person 4: 1,1
```

I want to generate personalized text to each one of them. For example.

```
Person 1: Your reliable friends are most likely your close family and you score 2 for your emotional intelligence. 

Person 2:  You find it very hard to trust people. Your EI score is 1.
```

etc.

Could we do this? Or it is difficult and highly unlikely? If so, can you advise me which course to take?

Comment: Are you using VBA to do this? If you are, would you be generating word document from Excel VBA?

Comment: @Zac could you supply us with a tutorial?

Comment: As long as you use 1 column for each question’s answers (and as long as there aren’t more than around 255 questions), it becomes something you might be able to solve using Word MailMerge (which would normally be off-topic here if there is no reason to use VBA too)

Comment: @slightly I don't think that this is true. There is combinations, how could we use them to generate different text

Comment: @rsc05 : Don’t think what is true? But let’s assume you have (logically) a bunch of code consists of a large set of if/then/else conditions or choices. You can  usually do that using IF fields and {.= } fields in Word, it’s just that it is harder to organise than a piece of (say) VBA code, particularly since you can only nest IF fields to about 19 or 20 levels). If you have conditions that need data from more than one row in the sheet, though, it gets much harder and is probably not worth attempting.

Comment: @slightlysnarky thank you so much for this, I think I might need a VBA code for this, but can you orient me to a certain tutorial or a lecture that teaches these kinds of tricks? I know basic VBA (I used it once a long time ago) but such an application would be useful for me.

Comment: You will probably find a lot more relevant examples of Field coding on the Microsoft Answers site. Broadly speaking you mainly need to look at the MERGEFIELD, IF, =, and COMPARE fields, with SET and REF for intermediate results, and bear in mind that you can work with numeric values by treating them either as logical values ({=or(x,y)} or as arithmetic values ( {=x+y+z}).